# setuptools tries (and fails) to install progressbar-2.3 when progressbar-2.3.dev0 is already installed. How to correctly formulate requirements?

Tags: python, installation, dependencies, setuptools

My package has a dependency on a package called `progressbar`.  There is a [bug in progressbar 2.3](https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/source/detail?spec=svn235f632a9c86d7a84c607151d5127652102549ab&r=3c94a3a1ebe1325c7c605cc8f11126dcc632b04d) causing installation in Python>3.3 to fail, therefore I installed the [latest git repo from this fork](https://github.com/coagulant/progressbar-python3) in a version calling itself `2.3.dev0`.  However, when I install my package with the `progressbar` dependency, it tries to install version `2.3`, which [fails due to the bug](https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/issues/detail?id=42).  This is what I have in my `setup.py':

```
setup(
    name = "pyatmlab",
    author = "Gerrit Holl",
    author_email = "g.holl@reading.ac.uk",
# (...)
    install_requires=["numpy>=1.10", "scipy>=0.16", "pyproj>=1.9",
                      "statsmodels>=0.6", "pytz>=2015.4", "progressbar>=2.3",
                      "matplotlib>=1.4"],
# (...)
)
```

What can I fix in `install_requires` to stop `setuptools` from trying to downgrade from `progressbar-2.3.dev0` to `progressbar-2.3`?  Even when I change the requirement to `progressbar>=2.3.dev0`, `pip install --upgrade` still tries to downgrade to `progressbar-2.3`.

Comment: My workaround has been to uncomment the requirement completely, but of course that is not desirable as it will lead to a failure at runtime.

Comment: what happens if you write `progressbar>2.3`?

Comment: What is the URL of the repo you installed?

Comment: @MattDMo `2.3.dev0` is from `https://github.com/coagulant/progressbar-python3.git`.  `2.3` is from pypi.  I've edited the question to add the former information.

Comment: @cel If I use `progressbar>2.3` rather than `progressbar>=2.3`, `pip install` fails with `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement progressbar>2.3` (whereas `2.3.dev0` is already installed).

Comment: @gerrit, but isn't that what you would expect? At the moment the latest version on pypi is buggy and thus does not satisfy the dependency. If you install the dependenciy directly with git, `pip` should not complain, because `2.3.dev` is  considered newer than `2.3`. And once there's a new release everything will be as normal again.

Comment: @cel The problem is that the other package has a dependency on `2.3.dev0`, but even though `2.3.dev0` is *already installed*, `pip` doesn't do what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

In your local copy of the repo, edit `progressbar/__init__.py` and change the following line:

```
__version__ = '2.3dev'
```

to

```
__version__ = '2.3.1'
```

Save the file, then reinstall with `pip`. Of course, without a pull request, this will only work locally for you.

---

Another option is to use the much more up-to-date [`progressbar2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar2), on Github [here](https://github.com/WoLpH/python-progressbar). It has been validated to work up to Python 3.5. Obviously, you'll have to test your code to ensure it works with the new version, but this is probably your best bet.

Comment: I was not aware of `progressbar2`.  Thanks for the pointer!  Barring that, I suppose your answer may be the only thing that works, even if it may not be the most desirable solution.  I'll wait with accepting to see if someone comes up with a solution that does not require changing the version number (in this case I will migrate to `progressbar2`, but the issue of `setuptools` misunderstanding poorly labelled versions can happen in other situations as well).